# Deploying Sharepoint App 2013 to Windows Azure (Provider Hosted)

Tags: c#, .net, azure, sharepoint-2013

I am learning sharepoint 2013 development and in the learning process, i am deploying the sharepoint 2013 web part to the windows azure. However as soon as i deploy this, i get the following message:

```
Error.
An error occurred while processing your request.
```

I have added the customerror key in web.config and set the mode to off. i have gone into windows azure itself and changed the detailed error message to On under site diagnostics but still i am getting no error details. i have also made sure that i am publishing with debug mode on rather than release mode. can anyone please help on how can i see the error details for a website hosted in windows azure? also the website is a MVC 4 Application.

Comment: I'll try to help you:  Diagnostics and Debugging in Windows Azure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh694035.aspx

Comment: i had already tried those steps but no more information that an error has occurred.

Comment: Are you using Virtual Machines? You could take a look on Event Viewer and IIS logs.

Comment: no i am not using a virtual machine. i just created the website.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's a silly answer, but The "Off" must be capitalized correctly.

Comment: yea that's not a problem.